# References for chromatic symmetric functions of hypergraphs

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, graph-theory, coloring, symmetric-functions

Define a *hypergraph* to be a pair $H = (V,E)$ where $V$ is a set of vertices and $E$ is any set of subsets of $V$ called *edges*.  Thus if every edge $U \in E$ has only two elements, then the hypergraph $H$ is equivalent to an ordinary simple graph.  We say that a coloring $\chi: V \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ of a hypergraph $H$ is *proper* for each $U \in E$ there are $u_1,u_2 \in U$ with $\chi(u_1) \neq \chi(u_2)$.  It might seem more natural to require that $\chi(u_1)\neq \chi(u_2)$ for every pair of distinct elements $u_1,u_2 \in U$, but then hypergraph colorings would be equivalent to graph colorings as we could replace every edge $U\in E$ with a clique.

Given a hypergraph $G = (V,E)$, define the chromatic symmetric function of $G$ to be $$X_G = \sum_{\chi} x^\chi$$ where the sum is over proper colorings $\chi$ of $G$, and $x^\chi = \prod_{v \in V} x_v$ with $x_1, x_2, \ldots$ being indeterminates.

I believe Stanley introduced the chromatic symmetric function of a hypergraph in the last section of [this](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/~cchauve/MATH445/PROJECTS/MATH445-DM-193-267.pdf) paper (pdf).  He computes $X_H$ for hypergraphs of the form $H = (V,E)$ where $E = \{S \subseteq V: |S| = k\}$.  But he writes:

> There is an extensive theory of hypergraph coloring, but little of
>   this theory is enumerative.

This was in 1995.  Is this statement still true?  What are some nice examples of work counting the number of proper colorings of hypergraphs?  In particular, are there other nice classes of hypergraphs $H$ for which we can compute $X_H$? Are there any conjectures as to when $X_H$ is Schur-positive? I am interested in cases where $H$ is not equivalent to an ordinary graph.

Comment: The paper you commented is not enabeled by now, do you mean this:
http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/100.pdf

Comment: Ah thanks for pointing this out.  I actually meant [this](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/papers/taor.pdf) paper, his second paper on chromatic symmetric functions.  The first one only deals with ordinary graphs.

Comment: It's been two years since I posted this question - I suppose I should answer it with a few references I've found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few references I've found since posting this question two years ago (including two of my own that I've written since then.)

- Vladimir Grujić, Tanja Stojadinović: [Hopf Algebras of Building Sets](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v19i4p42)
- C. Lenart and N. Ray: [Hopf algebras of set systems](http://www.albany.edu/~lenart/articles/inc_hopf.html) (and the references given there.) The symmetric function defined there for a set system for a simplicial complex is equivalent to the chromatic symmetric function of a certain hypergraph.
- My papers [Chromatic symmetric functions of hypertrees](http://arxiv.org/abs/1506.08262) and [Formal group laws and chromatic symmetric functions](http://fpsac2015.sciencesconf.org/71027/document)